# Applescript does not execute shell command

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, echo

I have an applescript

```
do shell script "echo -n -e \\\\x61\\\\x61\\\\x61 > /tmp/file.txt"
```

But the file.txt does not contain "aaa"!

It contains "-n -e aaa\n" instead.

Can someone help me with that problem?

Comment: `sh` echo does not support -n or -e options, they are a bash extension.  Try prefixing the command with `bash -c `

Comment: Or see if your system supports `printf` . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different versions of `echo` are hopelessly inconsistent in how they interpret command options (like `-n` and `-e`) and/or escape sequences in the string. It's not just bash vs. sh as cdarke said; it's much messier than that. The best thing to do is just avoid either one by using `printf` instead. It's a bit more complicated to use than `echo`, but completely worth it because your scripts won't break just because the latest version of the shell was compiled with different options(!).

In this case, using `printf` is actually even simpler than using `echo`, because it always interprets escape sequences (in its first argument, the "format string" -- the rest are different), and doesn't print a newline at the end (unless you explicitly tell it to with `\n` at the end of the format string). So your script becomes:

```
do shell script "printf \\\\x61\\\\x61\\\\x61 > /tmp/file.txt"
```

...although you can simplify it further by using single-quotes to keep the shell from interpreting escapes before they get to `printf`:

```
do shell script "printf '\\x61\\x61\\x61' > /tmp/file.txt"
```

(The escapes are still doubled, because they're being interpreted by AppleScript. But at least they don't need to be quadrupled anymore.)

(p.s. [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1638/))

Comment: Plus one for "relevant xkcd". Link still good four years later.